# How do I navigate and output html from an array?

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm storing different html-code via ajax in an array. I need to be able to navigate through the array, back and forth say, by clicking on buttons.

Here's what I have so far:

```
var query = {};
var query_array = [];
```

...then in jQuery ajax, under success:

```
success: function(stuff) {

                //var i = 0;

                query = stuff;
                query_array.push([query]);
                $('.area').html(stuff); /* output from database */
            }...
```

So far so good. Now here's the function that I'm trying to build:

```
var prev = $('#prev');

prev.on('click', function() {

    if (query_array.length < 1) {
        console.log('no items');
    }else{  
        console.log(query_array[0]); //works
        $('.area').html(query_array[0]); //works
        //$('.area').html(query_array[query_array.length-1]); //doesn't work
    }   
});
```

Can someone tell me what must be done to navigate through these arrays?

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(query_array[query_array.length-1]);`

Comment: Try  `$('.area').html(query_array[(Object.keys(query_array).length - 1)]);`

Comment: It's the same, that is, nothing happens. If I change from html to text, it outputs the text. So the issue is with html. the console.log works, too, just like text does.

Comment: This sounds stupid as .html() does this any way but try $('.area').empty().append(<html>)?

Comment: Still nothing. It seems that I must define the index of the array in order for the output to work. I need to have a point to define which point in the array I'm in. For instance, I'm at query 5, so if I go to 4, then 3, that point is refreshed each time.

Comment: Why are you pushing single element array to query_array - `query_array.push([query])` instead of pushing element directly to query_array - `query_array.push(query)`?

Comment: Chitrang: if I don't, I get this error: "Requested keys of a value that is not an object."

Comment: Can you post us a consol.log( query_array ) result? I suspect that the problem is about how you build the array

Comment: It looks like this:

["<div id="area>stuff</div>"...more html]...and yes, I suspect the same, Riccardo. query is an object, so maybe accessing the object ought to be different.